# Color targeting only :hover not just anchor

Tags: html, css

When using the pseudo selector :hover, the color changes (note big big style sheet, it is not however been overwritten); but when I apply it to the anchor tag itself it does not apply.

CSS:

```
#testimonialContent {
    width:640px;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Gotham-Book, Arial;
    color: #4d4d4f;
    *padding-top: 0;
}
#testimonialContent span {
    width: 600px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    letter-spacing: 0px\9;
    float: right;
    margin-top: -3px;
    *margin-top: -30px;

}

#testimonialContent span strong {
    position: relative;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    display: block;
    top: 8px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
#testimonialContent a{
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    position: relative;
    color: #86a53e;
    margin-top: -10px;
    float: right;   
}
#testimonialContent a:hover{
    color: red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="testimonialContent">
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><img id="quoteOne" src="http://www.qwertyuiop.co.uk/wp-content/themes/designworks2012/images/quote1.png">
    <span><?php
        query_posts(array(
            'cat' => 39,
            'order' => 'ASC', // ASCEND
            'orderby' => 'rand',
            'showposts' => 1,
            ));
        $wp_query->is_archive = true; $wp_query->is_home = false;
        if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        the_content();
        endwhile; endif;


    ?>
    <a href="#" id="nextQ">NEXT QUOTE</a>
    </span>
    <script>
        var str = $('#testimonialContent').html();
        var x = str.replace("<p>","");
        $('#testimonialContent').html(x);
        var x = str.replace("</p>","");
        $('#testimonialContent').html(x);
    </script>
</div> <!-- end testimonialContent -->
```

As I say, it is not being overwritten somewhere down the stylesheet. (placed it at the bottom).

EDIT:

I have a link, this link is displaying black however the css `color: #86a53e;` should target it. It does not. However the pseudo selector is targeting the anchor whereas the normal anchor is not. It will hover red but display black. It should not be black.

Comment: I don't understand you r question. Id didn't even understood the title. What is your problem? You have set the same color to plain links and their hover-state: `#testimonialContent a{ color: #86a53e; } #testimonialContent a:hover{ color: #86a53e; }` Now, what is not working as expected?

Comment: See my edit on the op :)

Comment: If you're using google chrome, you can use the dev tools to analyse the element and see if the styling is being overwritten by some other style rules - it sounds like this is a possibility worth looking into..

Comment: The example as posted seems to work for me, so the problem is probably somewhere else in the CSS. I also recommend using the dev tools to inspect the styles (all modern browsers have some, not just Chrome).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're aplyying the exact same color that It had before the :hover:

```
#testimonialContent a{
...
color: #86a53e;
...
}

#testimonialContent a:hover{
**color: #86a53e;**
}
```

If you change the second, you'll notice the behaviour you want.

Comment: Sorry, before the hover its displaying black where it should be displaying 86a53a, the :hover one was just for debug to check its targeting it in some shape or form, edited op